# Permission Set for Integration User profile: The user license doesn't allow the permission: View All Activities

Tags: api, integration, profile, permission-sets, userlicense

I created

- a new profile based on the new **Salesforce Integration** license,
- created a new user (*Portal API User*) using this license,
- have set the **Permission Set License Assignment** on this User to **Salesforce API Integration** and
- created a new **Permission Set** (I did not assign a license for it here - set to *None*) wherein I set the CRUD for the various objects (custom and standard), and various other permissions needed.

When I try and assign this Permission Set to the new API user I get the following error:

*Can't assign permission set Portal API to user Portal API User. The user license doesn't allow the permission: View All Activities*

[image]

I cannot find a permission setting for this anywhere, so have no clue what to do. I removed *View All* from every object, but still no luck.

What is it referring to?

**UPDATE: I eventually found the setting under App Permissions->Sales**

Comment: where can i find the app permissions

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur when you try to assign a permission set to a user who has a different user license type than the one required by the permission set.

For example, if the permission set requires a Salesforce license, but the user has a Salesforce Platform license, you will get this error. To resolve this issue, you can either:

- Change the user's license type to match the permission set's requirement. You can do this by editing the user record and selecting a different user license from the drop-down menu. Note that changing the user license may affect the user's access to other features and apps.
- Create a custom permission set that has the same permissions as the original one, but does not have a user license restriction. You can do this by cloning the original permission set and removing the user license requirement from the cloned one. Then, you can assign the cloned permission set to the user.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, but the whole point is that I want an Integration License user for doing API calls, so changing the license type defeats the point. The current Permission Set does not have a license associated with it (as mentioned in my post).  I need to know what the Permission Set is referring to when it talks about 'View All Activities' - there is no such setting anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Ah, I found it! I see it's under App Permissions -> Sales.
Took me forever to find it!